# configure nginx and apache2 on local machine at the same time

Tags: apache, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I want to have many localhosts on my local machine at the same time. 
For example, I want to have 'example1.local' on apache2 and 'example2.local' on nginx. In real life I want to have as many as I want for both type of servers. I installed apache2 and nginx using default manual. And both status active, no syntax errors.

I tried to restart both services and restart machine It doesn't matter.

here is my config for apache2 in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example1.local.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example1.local
    ServerAlias www.example1.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example1.local/index.php
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and default config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>      
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

here is config for nginx

```
server {
        listen 127.0.1.1:8080 default_server;
        listen [::]:8080 default_server;

        root /var/www/example2.local/;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

        server_name example2.local;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     }
}
```

and my hosts  `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       example1.local
127.0.1.1       example2.local
```

If I try example2.local I'm redirected to default apache2 localhost in `/var/www/html` but expected nginx ((((

Comment: nginx is listening on port 8080 not 80. so you have to http://example2.local:8080

Comment: ok but now I have ```This site can’t be reached```

Comment: and I dont  want to use port in domain address is it real ?